# ember replaceWith does not changes the url

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

How to perform some `replaceWith` to the same route but with a different parameter?

The route declaration is:

```
this.route('sampleRoute', { path: '/:param_name' });
```

This 'sampleRoute' route reproduces the problem: the URL does not changes after a `replaceWith` inside it.

```
let globalFlag = null;

export default Route.extend({
  afterModel() {

    console.log("welcome");

    if(globalFlag){
      console.log(this.router.location.getURL());
      console.log(this.paramsFor(this.routeName).param_name);
    } else {
      globalFlag = true;
      this.replaceWith(this.routeName, 'progValue');
    }
  }
});
```

Tried with beforeModel, model, afterModel. How to have the URL properly set before running some code?

Testing this route with http://localhost/sampleRoute/browserValue produces:

```
Expected output: 
    welcome
    welcome
    /sampleRoute/progValue
    progValue

Actual output:
    welcome
    welcome
    /sampleRoute/browserValue
    progValue
```

Comment: AFAIK the router will stay in the old location/URL until the targets route `afterModel` has successfully *finished*. So you're just to early.

Answer (score 1):

**If** the URL segment that comes after `/sampleRoute/` is not dynamic, I think you are looking for a nested route instead of a query param. Your router.js file would have:

```
this.route('sampleRoute', function() {
  this.route('someNestedRoute');
});
```

**Alternatively** if the segment is dynamic, then your router.js file to be:

```
this.route('sampleRoute');
```

Importantly, you do not need to specify params as a `path` option to your route.

In your model, `replaceWith` takes a hash for query params:

```
import { set } from '@ember/object';

export default Route.extend({
  globalFlag: null,

  beforeModel(transition) {
    super.beforeModel(transition);

    if (this.globalFlag){
      console.log('flag set');
    } else {
      set(this, 'globalFlag', true);
      this.replaceWith(this.routeName, transition.to.queryParams);
    }
  }
});
```

**But** I would question what you are trying to do here. You should be able to have ember's route and controller manage query params for you, and not need to `replaceWith` like this at all. I would check out the guide: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/

Comment: The final need is the one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328649/ember-change-current-url-and-linkto-targets-without-reloading-data/58418857#58418857