# Ember, change current url and LinkTo targets without reloading data

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

How to change an url and the LinkTo components without reloading data?

Figure an app where a user can change the name of his project. The current url contains the project name, so it must be updated. Nothing excepts the url and the links must be modified (no data reload)

Consider this main route:

```
this.route('routeName', { path: '/:project_name/:param2/:param3' }, function () {
  ...many sub routes
});
```

The replaceURL method allow to change the url:

```
this.router.location.replaceURL(urlWithNewProjectName)
```

Example of LinkTo usage (no model is specified, default values are used):

```
{{#LinkTo 'routeName'}}link{{/LinkTo}}
```

For example the following fails:

```
// this code in the router has no effect on LinkTo in templates.
const params = this.paramsFor(this.routeName);
params.project_name = "newName";
```

LinkTo components continue to target old urls. How to change a dynamic segment default value for a route?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `<LinkTo />`? My first instinct here is that you're passing a `model` into this helper which contains the name of the old project.

Comment: The LinkTo did not receive any models. Is there a way to update one time for all links the current values of dynamic-segment, in orderTo reflect the url change?

Comment: Sorry to make you go around again, but can you also add your `app/router.js` file where this link is specified. If you are not passing any dynamic content to `LinkTo` then I'm not sure where the name of the project gets into the URL.

Comment: No problem, I add it in the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the dynamic segments to the LinkTo component in the template. When those props change, the link will update. See the guides for more info starting here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/links/#toc_example-for-multiple-segments

Comment: Thanks you Patrick. What I specificly ask is, how to change a dynamic segment default value for a route? Like that all LinkTo will be updated. When no model is provided to linktos, it seems to use the last dynamic segments parsed from url.

Comment: It is not a common pattern to dynamically change `/` segments of the path. I think you are looking for query params. So you would remove `path: '/:project_name/:param2/:param3'` from your router.js. And use query params instead `?project_name=blah&param2=asdf&param3=wef`.